# How to format N+1 (as in engineering redundancy)

Tags: engineering

What is the best way to format "n+1" as in the engineering redundancy term.  For example, a computer has 2 power supplies so that either can fail and the system keeps running.  That would be n+1 (one spare).

Two ways I've considered are:

```
$n{+}1$
```

and

```
$n\,+1$
```

Comment: I'd say this is context dependent, as well as different conventions in different fields etc. Also, people will have different opinions based on personal preference. So all in all, I don't think this question is suited for this site because; a) it's primarily opinion-based, and b) this is mostly _not_ a (La)TeX specific question, but rather about typography/typesetting.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's about typography/typesetting – we have a few of those – but rather that there's no correct answer. This is a Q&A site – it's not meant to air "suggestions" ;-) Try chat or reddit.

Comment: I think @SeanAllred is correct that it is a typography/typesetting question.  If it is context dependent, then I'd like someone with expertise to tell me which contexts to use N vs n.

Comment: @TomOnTime But that isn't what this site is about, ultimately. As far as I know, there is no such site (save perhaps [GraphicDesign.SE](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), but I don't think it's very well-suited to that audience). This is very much something that's best to ask in chat (either ours or another site's, perhaps [EE.SE](//electronics.stackexchange.com)) so you can receive multiple valid responses and gauge some sort of consensus. *There is no right answer to this question.*

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, there might be. But, if there is, it is an *engineering* question not a TeX question. That is, it might be that, in engineering, this should always be typeset in a particular way and any other presentation would cause readers to confuse redundancy with some-other-thing. If so, there is (relative to engineering) a correct answer. But the question is not then about TeX and is best put to engineers.

Comment: @cfr Fair enough :) I guess it's akin to whether to use big-O or little-O in complexity theory; the two mean very different things. It could be the same in engineering. (But yes, this is definitely not a TeX question.) :)

Comment: @SeanAllred In many logical systems, `A` and `a` mean very different things. Although, in this case, it isn't even enough to ask a logician. The question could only be answered for a particular logical system ;). (Although some general guesses based on how-most-systems-do-this could reasonably be made.)